# How to refer multiple schema in my mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am creating a website where you can take and upload tests.
So there are two kinds of users Company(upload test) and Candidate(take test).
Now when i create a token how do I refer to both the schema's (schema of company and schema of candidate)?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

let tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "<?>" }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Token", tokenSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's sat this is how you export both candidate and company schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Candidate", candidateSchema)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Company", companySchema)
```

Your token schema should be like the following:

```
let tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

candidateId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "Candidate" },

comoanyId:{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Company" },

);
```